# Rust max of multiple floats?

Tags: floating-point, rust

Here is the simple question, I'm writing a function that returns max value of multiple floats, `std::cmp::max` gives me:

```
the trait bound `{float}: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
```

Do I need to write this for every project:

```
macro_rules! max {
    ($x: expr) => ($x);
    ($x: expr, $($z: expr),+) => {{
        let y = max!($($z),*);
        if $x > y {
            $x
        } else {
            y
        }
    }}
}
```

So what is the recommended way to get max value of multiple floats?

Comment: You might be interested in the [`float-ord` crate](https://crates.io/crates/float-ord).

Comment: @E_net4iskindandwelcoming Yeah, I noticed that question, but do I need to create a vector to get the max value?

Comment: No, not really. The duplicate applied to your question is that `std::cmp::max` expects a type that implements `Ord`, but no floating point type implements it for the reasons explained in the answer. You can take a wrapper around `f32` and `f64` that produces an unambiguous total order.

Comment: Note that there is [`f32::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f32.html#method.max) and [`f64::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.f64.html#method.max)

Comment: @Jmb Thanks, that's a good way, but still write several `max` method.

Comment: *Do I need to write this* — note that your suggested code does not handle NaN values correctly; `(max!(f64::NAN, 0.0), max!(0.0, f64::NAN))` will result in `(0, NaN)`